# Moving large files with cronjob: What happens if mv still running when next run?

Tags: cron, mv

On a Ubuntu 16.04 headless system, I have two directories. I want a cronjob to move every file from directory A to directory B (same partition, same hard drive, same file system etc.). The problem is/might be: The files will be quite large and for some reasons the cronjob has to run quite often, like every minute or so.

So, the following scenario is quite likely: cronjob starts for the first time, finds a big file in directory A, starts moving it to directory B. While the mv process is still running, the cronjob is executed for the second time. Will this cause any problems?

I've found this question and ansers [What happens when multiple processes try to mv the same files between two different filesystems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/247454/what-happens-when-multiple-processes-try-to-mv-the-same-files-between-two-differ), but I think that's about simultaneously started processes. I hope, there is a way for cronjobs to prevent unwanted behavior.

Comment: "but I think that's about simultaneously started processes" s/started/running/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> While the mv process is still running, the cronjob is executed for the second time. Will this cause any problems?

It can yes.

Generally I would advice to create a script, put a mutual exclusion lock (MUTEX) in that script and stop executing the script if the lock exists and remove the lock when the "mv" is done from the first cronjob.

A very basic example:

```
if mkdir /var/lock/mylock; then
  mv your_file /to/a/directory/
  rm -rf /var/lock/mylock
else
  exit 1
fi
```